# Complication in summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How do I deal with this summation?

$$\sum_{j=n}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{n+j}$$

Do I just substitute all j's with n? That seems to be too easy.

*edit: This is a part of a larger problem, which is to find the limit of the summation as n tends to infinity.

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with this summation"?

Comment: What it means is to replace  with all numbers between n and 2n-1 and add all those numbers. $\frac{1}{n+n}+\frac{1}{n+n+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+2n-1}$. start with what $j=$ and end at what is above the $\sum$ sign, counting up j by 1 for each new term.

Comment: What exactly are you asked to do?Is this part of a bigger problem?

Answer (score 1):

One can make the change of index $k=n+j$ giving
$$
\sum_{j=n}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{n+j}=\sum_{k=2n}^{3n-1} \frac{1}{k}=H_{3n-1}-H_{2n-1}, \qquad n\ge1,
$$ where $H_n$ is the classic [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Here is another solution from wolframalpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(n%2Bj)+from+j%3Dn+to+j%3D2*n-1)

Comment: @Aaron Hendrickson The Wolframalpha expression is coherent with my answer above since one may recall the digamma function is such that $\psi(n)=H_{n-1}-\gamma$ (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers)

Comment: @OliverOloa Yes I understand. It's just another form of the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint #1:  In general, simplifying the sum of unit fractions is **not easy**.

Hint #2:  Evaluating a sum given a summation notation **is easy** if you know the index of summation, the lower and upper limits for the index, and the general formula for the summands.

Comment: #1 Do you think to egyptian fraction ? #2 You should add : "and if this formula depends by a polynomial formula on the index of summation", otherwise, your remark about "easiness" has no basis.

Answer (score 0):

If $u_n$ denotes the sum and you are asked if sequence $(u_n)$ converges when $n \to \infty$, the answer is yes; Moreover, the limit is $\ln(3/2)$.

Here is why: we can write

$$u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{k=n-1}\frac{1}{2n+k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{k=n-1}\frac{1}{2+\dfrac{k}{n}}$$ which tends, as a Riemann sum, to

$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{2+x}dx=\ln(\dfrac32).$$